# FMA European conference vs. EFMA annual conference

Tags: academic-graduate

There are two large financial economics conferences in Southern Europe this June:

1. FMA European conference (June 12-14 in Turin)
2. EFMA annual conference (June 26-29 in Lisbon)

I would like to go to one of them, but I am not sure which one. Could anyone outline the main differences between these conferences? Is one considered to be more prestigious than the other? Or otherwise more attractive?

What I can see from last year's programs ([FMA](https://www.fmaconferences.org/Aalborg/AalborgProgram.htm) and [EFMA](https://www.efmaefm.org/0EFMAMEETINGS/EFMA%20ANNUAL%20MEETINGS/2023-UK/EFMA2023DetailedProgram.pdf)) is this:

- The topics are quite similar, though there are so many contributions that it is not so easy to get a good overview.
- FMA appears to be smaller.